# Create a HealthCheck to a non-api project for liveness probe openshift

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, openshift

I have a project that just consumes messages from Rabbit MQ, and I'm using **Net Core 2.1.**. I just create a "Console Application" with hosted service and everything is working fine.

Now I need to deploy it to Openshift and configure Liveness Probe, So I have 2 options:

1. Create an API in my application to respond when /health URL is called. Remember that I don't have ASP.NET Core dependencies in my project, I will need to add a lot of dependencies just because of /health URL. Anti-Pattern maybe ??
2. Make Liveness Probe execute a command inside my POD (like `ps -eaf`) to check if my application is running. I really think this can return a "false-positive" and not very accurate like /health.

So, what is the best solution and most used for a worker using Openshift Liveness Probe ?

Comment: You could also just point right to your index page. It doesn't _need_ to be some special API endpoint, it just needs a successful HTTP code

Comment: I just have a console app, I don't have kestrel or httpSys or something else. I will need start it.

Comment: So it's just a CLI app? What is it _doing_? You don't really want your LivenessProbe to be testing end-to-end functionality, you just want to make sure it's running and doing its job, whether that's listening for http, sending output, something). If your app isn't already doing http, then it's probably overkill to add an API endpoint

Comment: Yeah, this is my point. Make a http just to do health is overkill. But I would like to know what is better way to grant liveness probe in a console application

Comment: I think the best practice is to _have_ a LivenessProbe, but we can't even begin to tell you best practices on _how_ to implement it, since it really depends on your application architecture. From the k8s documentation, "Many applications running for long periods of time eventually transition to broken states, and cannot recover except by being restarted. Kubernetes provides liveness probes to detect and remedy such situations.". So, whatever makes sense for your application. If not an HTTP response, maybe provide a special argument that returns some information when ran?

Answer (score 1):

A light weight option compared to kestrel is HttpListener if its simply for a health check

Comment: This is not the problem, use kestrel or httplisterner or something else. I would like to know if this is the better way to do with openshift, following the best practices.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is still relevant for you but it might help others, according to RedHat's [Blog](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/liveness-and-readiness-probes) you can simply use TCP Sockets or Container Commands.